# NullPointerException when refreshing the recyclerview

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

So I have an AsyncTask class to handle populating my `RecyclerView`. It works well but when it needs to be refreshed then it crashes with a `NullPointerException`. I kind of know why but then I can't do it because I am creating a new `object` and adding it to my `list`.

This is my code:

```
  @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            try {
                userslist.clear();
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
                for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    ...
                    UsersData usersData = new UsersData(var1, var2);
                    userslist.add(UsersData);
                }
                cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Culprit line, despite the list being deleted and added again in the try block
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I suspect is it something to do with the `userslist`.

This is my error logs:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at lukazs.newapp.UserInfo$GetUserList.onPostExecute(UserInfo.java:218)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:741)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:197)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:654)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
```

EDIT: This is the method call where I populate the `recyclerview`:

```
public void populateRecyclerList(){
    GetUserList getUserList = new GetUserList();
    getUserList.execute();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    setContentView(R.layout.usersdetails); 
    populateRecyclerList();
    }
```

This is where `cAdapter` is initialised, in `onCreate` method:

```
RecyclerView.Adapter cAdapter;
ArrayList<UserDetailsProvider> userslist = new ArrayList<UserDetailsProvider>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleMusic);
    cAdapter = new UserDefinedAdapter(userslist);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(cAdapter);
    populateRecyclerList();
}
```

EDIT: I have done something now, but the `populateRecyclerList()` is crashing in another `AsyncTask class` on `onPostExecute`. Basically, I want to repopulate the recyclerView after a user has been added. This is my code for the `onPostExecute()` method, where I am calling the `populateRecyclerList()` method:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
           populateRecyclerList();
        }
```

Maybe you are not meant to call this method here? But then how would I update the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Maybe the only relevant part of code is missing. The exception is being fired inside onPostExecute method of AsyncTask

Comment: The `onPostExecute` method is there

Comment: Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what is at UserInfo.java line 218

Comment: @g2o ` cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: are passing / updating the arraylist in the adapter?

Comment: Your post is misleading. Why do you include two `onCreate()` methods? Why does one have a `populate();` method and the other a `populateRecyclerList();` method? What is `populateRecyclerList();` even doing?

Comment: apologies, it was a typo - it is meant to be `populateRecyclerList()`. I updated my post

Comment: Where are you setting the layout for this activity? Did you just not include that in your post? I don't see `setContentView(...)` which might be why the lookup of your `RecyclerView` is returning null.

Comment: In `onCreate` - `setContentView(R.layout.usersdetails)`; The code works but when I call it in the `asynctask` class it crashes

Comment: You really need to just post the relevant parts of your code because it is confusing the way you are doing it in pieces. Post a single `onCreate()` with all your code and remove the other one. You might also want to include the layout file in the`recyclerView` is turning up null.

Comment: You're calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` before you initialize. Your flow is incorrect. Just because you called an `AsyncTask` before you set the adapter, does not mean that the data will be ready. Instead you should initialize your `RecyclerView` set an empty adapter, and then update your adapter via callback when your `AsyncTask` is done and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: I have done that though! This bug is getting on my nerves! I have done bloody everything I could - unless if I am calling the `populateRecyclerList();` in the `onPostExecute()` method in another inner AsyncTask class - I have updated my post

Answer (score 1):

Your `cAdapter` is not initialized when you call `cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

**EDIT:**
Call your `populateRecyclerList()` after initilize your fields

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleMusic);
    cAdapter = new UserDefinedAdapter(userslist);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(cAdapter);

    populateRecyclerList();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It still crashes! This bug is a real pig

Comment: @g2o OP should not be required to create a new adapter if things are set up correctly.

Comment: with the same error? please post the line where it crashed?

Comment: `NullPointerException` on `recyclerView.setAdapter(cAdapter);`

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan yes I understand but if you see error cAdapter is not initialized

Comment: BTW `cAdapter` is initialised in the `onCreate()` method

Comment: In another comment you wrote exception occurs at `cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. Here you write it occurs at `recyclerView.setAdapter(cAdapter)`. `NullPointerException` means that you are invoking a method on a null instance. Which is the null instance? The RecyclerView or the Adapter?

Comment: I see two `onCreate` method on your post? I think the problem is there. What is the difference between `populateRecyclerList();` and `populate()`

Comment: Hi, I got this `recyclerView.setAdapter(cAdapter)` after writing the above code. This `NullPointerException` is a bitch

Comment: @LukazsPioetrszci could you provide full code of your Activity (with layout too)?

Comment: Sorry it was meant to be `populateRecyclerList()`

Comment: Still crashes. Grrr `NullPointerException`

Comment: Don't worry , be patient ;) please edit the post with your changes and remove the first `onCreate()`. And edit the error logcat so we can help you.

Comment: I believe it is the fact that I am calling the `populateRecyclerList()` in another `Asynctask` class. Basically that class adds the user and then updates the `RecyclerView` - I updated it in my OP. Please could you have a look

Answer (score 0):

My bad, onPostExecute DOES run on the UI thread... Thanks you guys for correcting...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

"onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter."

Comment: The [`AsyncTask.onPostExecute`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) method runs on the UI thread.

Comment: where in the UI do I put it?